# Selenium - Unable to launch browser java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okio/Sink

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Issue** : When I run browser launch code then getting below error:
Env : Windows
Java 1.8
Selenium 3.141.59
Browser - Chrome 94  ( Correct crome driver used)

@Test
public  void test() {

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resources\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
         options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
         options.addArguments("--enable-automation");
          options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");          
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);         
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://test.com");            
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        System.out.println("Loading the application url");
        
   }
```

Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okio/Sink

```
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponse(RealCall.java:229)
at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:198)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:160)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.OkHttpClient.execute(OkHttpClient.java:103)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:105)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:157)
at Base.BrowserLaunch.test(BrowserLaunch.java:34)
```

Please let me know if any other details required.

Comment: add `--` in these two as well `options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
         options.addArguments("--enable-automation");`

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue some time ago. I have used this code and hope it will help you as well.

```
Properties p=Someutility.getTestConfig();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", p.getProperty("driverPath"));
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.navigate().to(p.getProperty("navigationUrl"));
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Where `getTestConfig()` is the method where I get the properties file for use like to get the `driverPath` and `navigationUrl`.

Where `navigationUrl` is the url where my application is running.

Here is the `getTestConfig()` method for reference.

```
public static Properties getTestConfig() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("pathoffile/somefile.properties");
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(reader);
    return p;

}
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me . Also getting exception on line "driver = new ChromeDriver();" and already chromedriver.exe correctly . This error will not resolve by implementing properties file.

Comment: properties file is there to get the driver path and navigation url only.